# Updating Progress bar from a different thread in Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, dispatcher

I am trying to update a dialog which contains a label and a progress bar. Actually in my Application I am taking back up of my data, while taking the backup, I wanted to show the progress bar and a label showing what is currently being backed up. I invoke the progress using this

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Action)(() => { dialog.ProgressbarValue = "Backing up first item"; }));
```

This works fine on Windows 8, but nothing is getting updated on Windows 7.

Comment: Did you try any other DispatcherPriority, perhaps `Background`?

Comment: Yes, `DispatcherPriority.Send` does not work even on Windows 8. `DispatcherPriority.Loaded` works on Windows 8 but not on Windows 7

Comment: Why don't you use Normal priority ? This should work the same regardless of OS version.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu Normal priority is now updating anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle` actually fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You will required to have the Refresh applied on your textbox so it will display all the texts while the loop is running.

You will require to have a static class for ExtensionMethods that will contain your refresh routine.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

        public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
        {
            uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
        }
    }
```

Call this extentionMethod from your code after each time you set dialog.ProgressbarValue
Note: you do not need to have Dispatcher in this logic simple set dialog.ProgressbarValue in code and call above refresh method using dialog.Refresh();